# How to export installed pip packages

Tags: python, pip

A couple of days ago, I installed a .whl package using pip. But the .whl got deleted somehow from the filesystem. Now, I need to export or get that particular installed pip package.

Can I get some assistance in this regard please?

Thanks,
Nouman

Comment: You want a list of installed pip packages?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recreate a wheel from an installed package — there are not enough development files. You have to get the wheel from its original source.